# Get checkbox second parameter value in an onClick Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

How can i get the second value from the navbar onClick function so I can automatically select an option from the dropdown list below.

Any help is much appreciated.

Navbar

```
    <div class="btn-group m-b-1" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary btn-outline active" onclick="load_content_table(1, 5);">
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> A
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-outline btn-primary" onclick="load_content_table(1, 1);">
            <input type="checkbox"> B
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-outline btn-primary" onclick="load_content_table(1, 4);">
            <input type="checkbox"> C
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-outline btn-primary" onclick="load_content_table(1, 6);">
            <input type="checkbox"> D
        </label>
    </div>
```

Dropdown

```
<select name="search_type" required="" id="id_search_type">
  <option value="" selected="">---------</option>

  <option value="5">A</option>

  <option value="1">B</option>

  <option value="4">C</option>

  <option value="6">D</option>
</select>
```

Javascript

```
//get ID
var $select = $('#id_search_type');
$('label').click(function () {
    $select.val( $(this).data('select') );
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "second value"?

Comment: Do you mean second value at onclick function parameters?

Comment: yes that is correct 'onclick="load_content_table(1, 6);"' for this case, its the 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function load_content_table(a, b) {
  /* your code here */
  $('#id_search_type').val(b);
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it works Thanks a lot!

'function load_content_table(project_id, search_type_id) {
    var $select = $('#id_search_type');
    $('label').click(function () {
        $('#id_search_type').val(search_type_id);
    });'